# java.exe opens up hundreds of ports on 127.0.0.1 on a windows 10 computer and listens to itself

Tags: windows-10, java, port, tcp, netstat

After I ran `netstat -ab` with admin right on my win10 computer, which is not running anything "java" related on the desktop nor there is "java.exe" in taskmanager's "detailed view". (the computer's name is `MH507192`) I got about 150 items that look like the following:

```
[java.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49772        MH507192:49771         ESTABLISHED
 [java.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49773        MH507192:49774         ESTABLISHED
 [java.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49774        MH507192:49773         ESTABLISHED
 [java.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49775        MH507192:49776         ESTABLISHED
 [java.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49776        MH507192:49775         ESTABLISHED
 [java.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49777        MH507192:49778         ESTABLISHED
 [java.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49778        MH507192:49777         ESTABLISHED
 ...
 ...
 [java.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50045        MH507192:50046         ESTABLISHED
 [java.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50046        MH507192:50045         ESTABLISHED
 [java.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50047        MH507192:50048         ESTABLISHED
 [java.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50048        MH507192:50047         ESTABLISHED
 [java.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50049        MH507192:50050         ESTABLISHED
 [java.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50050        MH507192:50049         ESTABLISHED
```

I can't explain, don't know if this is normal, nor can I find the right terminologies to google this with.

Comment: check the process id and see the path where it is started from, might give you a hint what is happneing.

Comment: Yes, use Process Explorer to get a tree view to see the parent and potentially further up the tree.